# Is it safe to use customized CFLAGS for linux kernel, e.g mmx sse instructions

Tags: linux, kernel

Is it safe to use customized CFLAGS while compiling linux kernel, e.g enable SSE, MMX instructions, is that a problem ?

Comment: I think the kernel makefiles already pick decent flags. I'd be wary of changing them, as the kernel source sometimes uses code that just happens to work with the expected version of GCC and may not be robust to unexpected compiler flags.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a custom kernel then you are already playing with features which may or may not work depending on version of GCC (as mentioned by GillieS) and other factors. So deciding to enable SSE, MMX and so forth, probably doesn't introduce any more 'risk'. Basically, you are going to need to test your custom kernel extensively anyway, so it depends on what you call 'safe'.

If you are building modules (device drivers) for an existing kernel, then you really do need to use the same GCC as the kernel and the CFLAGS selected by the appropriate makefiles or you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The `Processor type and features` -> `Processor family` kernel configuration setting already sets up appropriate CFLAGS for you.

It also makes sure that any hand-written assembler segments in the kernel get replaced with SSE/MMX/whatever-approriate optimized versions at the same time (if necessary). Just changing CFLAGS alone won't do that.